Custom Attributes - pass multiple parameters
I have a view model (which is populated with data from a DB query), some properties have a custom attribute assigned to them. In this custom attribute I pass the name of the property that it is assigned to, but I also want to pass in a another property to be able to get its value so that I can pass these two pieces of information to another screen.
public int Id {get; set;}

[TestAttribute(nameof(Id), nameof(Name))]
public string Name {get;set;}

Is this doable? I know who to do it with custom validation attribute but can't seem to find anything for just an attribute which is making me think it's not possible.

you mean something like this(simple usage of string array instead string with params keyword) ... as you see, it compiles ... now you need to implement your custom validation

I have managed to that far but slightly differently (accepting them as two separate parameters, rather than a string array), but, my issue is how get the value of the properties from the viewmodel?

Via reflection model -> get type -> get custom attributes -> check if instance of yours -> cast -> use it

What exactly is your question?  Is it, How can I declare and apply an attribute with a variable number of parameters?  If so, see Can I initialize a C# attribute with an array or other variable number of arguments?.  If your question is, How can I "pass these two pieces of information to another screen"?  If so, there's not enough information to answer, we need to see a [mcve] showing exactly what you are trying to do and where you are stuck.  Also be sure to include the framework + version you are using.  Thanks!
